# GUID reference(s) missing from stream

Tags: intersystems-iris

I met this Jenkins build problem when commit to P4.

ERROR #5001: GUID reference(s) missing from stream websys/TranslationType/questionnaire.QCNXXCVD.Edit/68D7225A-DE63-11EB-AF4C-005056B66BA0.xml; 35551C28-0C38-11EB-A1C8-005056B66BA0

So how can I solve this problem. Would anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: We’d love to help you, but your question lacks information and clarity. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Eduard! What is P4? Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

input by Jack Huser · Aug 26, 2021

This error means that you have some element modified in TrakCare as Site level (or deleted), but the Questionnaire is Region Level. To solve this issue, you should check in TrakCare what GUID is missing:
Tools >> Change Control >> Find GUID

[image: img1]
Check which component should have been saved as Region level or has been removed.

Once you have it saves as Region Level you will be able to commit to P4.

I checked in Perforce and it seems the component was deleted on 6 november 2020 with JIRA TC-260035 but recreated on 1st august 2021 with JIRA TC-301371.
[image: img2]
So your problem should have been solved.
Regards,Jacques